# How long does the share link on the entry edit screen last?

Tags: link, editing, token

We're noticing that links to hidden entries that are shared via token (share button) eventually expire.

How long do these links last? Is there a setting to adjust how long the token will last?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

24 hours by default, but it can be configured via the `defaultTokenDuration` config setting.

- [v2 documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#defaulttokenduration)
- [v3 documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#defaulttokenduration)

Comment: Hi Brad, is there anywhere else in Craft other than the share link using this time token thing? I'm just trying to figure out what would be the impact of changing the duration setting.