# What does defaultTokenDuration affect besides hidden entries' share links?

Tags: config, token

Per [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/21986/5072), configuring `defaultTokenDuration` is the way to change the lifespan of hidden entries' share links from the default 24 hours. The v2 docs describes this as affecting "system tokens" but no further explanation of system tokens is provided. The v3 docs refers simply to "tokens."

[edit: I believe one other thing this controls is the lifespan of password reset tokens.]

I'd like to increase the lifespan of draft entries' share links, but wonder what other consequences I should take into account before changing `defaultTokenDuration`. What all does it affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (as of Craft 3.0), it will affect entry and category share links.  Some additional things might be using it in the upcoming 3.1 and plugins are free to use it for whatever they want.

For example, in Commerce 2, it is used for creating product preview share links.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Has this changed significantly in 3.1+, Brad? It'd be helpful to understand the scope of `defaultTokenDuration` in the documentation.